# How can I get consistent line heights in view and edit mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

As the screen below, I have a Read component + a Edit component.

But they don't exactly match, **the Edit still takes more spacing**.

My goal is to make them match, in order to later make an Edit Inline.

I've already tried with a few "td" and "tr" tags, but the issue was the same.

**I need same spacing between my "p" tags, for all lines. Right now some lines dosnt have the same spacing.**

[image]

**ReadOnlyRow.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const ReadOnlyRow = ({getData}) => {
  return (
    <>
    <p> Email : {  getData.data?.attributes?.email }</p>
    <p> Username :  </p>
    <p> Timezone :</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default ReadOnlyRow;
```

**EditableRow.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const EditableRow = ({getData}) => {
  return (
    <>
    <p>
    <label for="email"> Email : </label>
    <input type="email" placeholder={getData.data?.attributes?.email} name="email"></input>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="email"> Username : </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username .." name="username"></input>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="email"> Timezone : </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your timezone .." name="timezone"></input>
    </p>

    </>
  );
};

export default EditableRow;
```

**ParentFile.js**

```
return (
    <ProfileStyled>
      <h1> Profile </h1>
      <div className="profile-infos">

        <div className='row'>
          <div className='column'>
            <div className="user-infos">
              <form>
              <ReadOnlyRow getData={getData} />
              </form>
              <EditableRow getData={getData} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='row'>
          <div className='column'>
            <hr className="hr"/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='row'>
          <div className='column'>
            <div className="user-history">
              <p> History :</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </ProfileStyled>
  );
```

**CSS**

```
const ProfileStyled = styled.div`
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.greenLight};

  .hr {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }

  .profile-infos {
    max-width: ${(props) => props.theme.spacings.maxWidth};
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0 ${(props) => props.theme.paddings.NavLaptop};
    display: flex;
  }

  .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.user-infos {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.user-history {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}
 
`;
```

Comment: basically you're trying to make your inputs end in the same position?

Comment: I need same spacing between my "p" beacons, for all lines. Right now some lines dosnt have the same spacing.

Comment: A much simplified scenario with just two rendered paragraphs, one in regular and one in edit mode, would help us help you. This is a CSS issue and we don't need to see your React app.

Comment: You probably don't want to wrestle with spacing. Make the lines themselves the same height. In other words, give your paragraphs a min-height or put each in a container that limits height.

I'll be happy to explain further if you can show us rendered markup.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you needed a better way to space your `p` elements inside `EditableRow.js` and `ReadOnlyRow.js`.

I made this implementation with display grid, you can use this implementation if you don't have any problem with the supported browsers, you can check that [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid).

You need to add the css on the parent container, and then you can change `ReadOnlyRow.js`, so the user information is inside a `span` and then you have a similar structure on both components.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container p {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 200px;
  background: pink;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p> Email : <span>fake@email.com</span></p>
  <p> Username : </p>
  <p> Timezone :</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    <label for="email"> Email : </label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="fake@email.com" name="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email"> Username : </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username .." name="username" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email"> Timezone : </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your timezone .." name="timezone" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @pedrofromperu you can also modify the height inside the css I added there

Comment: No problem, I just set a specific height so it matches

Comment: Looking good, but the input paragraphs are 21px high. :) Also, I'd use `min-height` to allow for wrapping if necessary.